# How to implement LinkedIn auth with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, firebase-authentication, linkedin-api

My Ionic app has different ways of authentications, includes `Google, LinkedIn` , right now `firebase` doesn't support `linkedIn` out of the box, but it seems that there is a way to use custom authentication and using `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken`,

Can any one give me some 1,2,3,4 instruction about it?

Comment: Did you implement it successfully? I'm trying to do the same and any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, unfortunately LinkedIn deprecated the oauth1, and the solution I used is not working any more (https://github.com/zyra/cordova-plugin-linkedin/issues/66)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to authenticate and sign in with a token using a firebase function for LinkedIn authentication. This has not been pushed into production yet. Here's a link to the GitHub repository for LinkedIn authentication.

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/linkedin-auth

Answer (score 0):

This question looks interesting. I am also researching. I am providing some useful links.

https://jwt.io/ -- you can find third party JWT libraries for Android here. Because Firebase uses SON Web Tokens (JWTs) based authentication.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library

We can't create custom tokens in Firebase Admin SDK. But we can create custom tokens from Firebase Authenticating server. Explanation is here: h[ttps://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens)

```
String uid = "some-uid";
HashMap<String, Object> additionalClaims = new HashMap<String, Object>();
additionalClaims.put("premiumAccount", true);

FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String customToken) {
            // Send token back to client
/* Here, you get the custom token. You can simply store this token in String variable, and later pass as customToken */
        }
    });
```

This link "https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt" provides APIs to create Custom JWT tokens. After you create custom tokens, you can use

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(mCustomToken)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCustomToken:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(CustomAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Note: I have not implemented this before. I am one of the very interested people in implementing this. I will follow your answer when you solve this completely.**